# How to find all possible solutions with backtracking search?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, backtracking, graph-coloring

I want to solve a problem very similar to graph-coloring with the backtracking search, but I want to get "all" of the solutions to the problem and not just one possible solution.

How should I change the below algorithm that is stated in the book "Artificial Intelligence, the modern approach" to get all the solutions? ( assume that the number of nodes(variables) is not a lot (for example n<100) so that we can have all the solutions.)

[image]

Comment: sounds like the number of solutions is exponential to the number of nodes - so will probably be the calculation time. are you sure you need ALL solutions?

Comment: @draz Yes, the number of my variables is low and so that it is possible to find all.

Comment: @Not_Founded Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Please [edit] your question to include the exact problem you have, where you have problems changing the algorithm or any other problems you have. Currently your question is very broad.

Comment: @Progman thanks for your comment, I think it is clear, I asked how I can change the above algorithm so that we can get all possible solutions instead of just one solution .

Comment: @Not_Founded You haven't wrote what the problem is to change the algorithm you currently have. What are the issues you have, where do you stuck in changing the algorithm? Otherwise your question/post is too broad.